# Using link-dest thwarted by permissions

Tags: rsync, backup, hard-link

I'm trying to do a weekly archive of a source folder using the previous week as a source for link-dest.

However, the actual source folder has one set of permissions (on files) that differ from what rsync ends up creating in the archive. I have purposely not enabled --perms. It seems that rsync will refuse to link the link-dest files if the permissions do not match, but this is very unfortunate as I have told the transfer to not try to match the permissions so now they will not match. Ever.

This may be a bug or oversight in rsync where it does not match destination file and a link-dest file based on the would be destination attributes but instead and stubbornly on the source attributes.

My question: is this a "bug"? Is there a workaround for my use case? Or am I forced to preserve permissions?

P.S. Note that the behavior seems to be the polar opposite for owner. Rsync will never prevent linking based on ownership difference between source and link-dest, even if I do tell it to preserve ownership.